# Get the specific characters from a string

Tags: sql-server-2008

> Hello,
>
> I have the following strings samples. I need a query to return 7th and 8th
>   character in a string.

```
600110710180  -- the result is 71
600200487090  -- the result is 48
604500820033  -- the result is 82
```

> Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for :

```
SUBSTRING(stringSample, startPosition, length);
```

Where "stringSample" is the string you're working on, "startPosition" is the position where you start your character extraction, and "length" is the number of characters you want to extract.

So here, in your case :

```
SUBSTRING(600110710180,7,2);
```